# Why this code is not changing

Tags: php, oop

In the code below I would expect that `real_change` and `change` methods to change the variable `$n` passed by reference in the constructor.

```
abstract class y {
  private $x;

  function __construct(&$x) {
    $this->x = &$x;
  }

  function real_change() {
    $this->x = 'real change';
  }
}

class x extends y {    
  function change() {
    $this->x = 'changed';
  }
}

$n = 'intact';
$c = new x($n);
$c->change(); 
echo $n.PHP_EOL; // prints "intact"
$c->real_change();
echo $n.PHP_EOL; // prints "real change"
```

Why is this happening?

How could I achieve to create a method in an abstract class that modifies a variable referenced in a property?

Many thanks.

Comment: Set the property as `protected` instead?

Comment: Stackoverflow did not allowed me to vote that same moment when I saw your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your abstract class, `$x` is marked as private, so it's not available to your extended class. `$this->x` will essentially just create a new public `$x` variable in `class x`.

If you set the variable to `protected` it will give access to all extended classes, and allow you to set it properly.

See updated playground [here](https://3v4l.org/RurmU).

More information on visibility via the PHP docs, can be found [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).